# How to install ipython

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, ipython

I am trying to install IPython using `pip install ipython`, but I keep getting an error message:

> Error message: "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Garrett\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-n12hw04f\simplegeneric.
> ".

I saw other questions regarding the error message, although not pertaining to ipython, and followed the steps. I made sure `setuptools` was installed and updated, but when it comes to installing ez_setup, I am given the same error as when I am trying to install ipython.

I am using Python version 3.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the environment from scratch, and install the Anaconda distribution from [Anaconda Installers](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#Downloads)

`ipython` comes installed with this distribution.

`ipython` can be upgraded by `conda upgrade ipython`